# Remove prefix from Soap response

Tags: soap, jax-ws, java-17

Trying to move from java8 to java17. Same request was being used in java8 too. But in java8 response , not seeing namespace - `"xmlns:SOAP-ENV"`  , also  `<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>`.

So I need to remove -->  namespace - `"xmlns:SOAP-ENV"` , also `<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>`

Using jars :
jakarta.xml.ws : jakarta.xml.ws-api : 4.0.0

Also using wsdl (not xslt)

Using class - `SoapMsgHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`

Request :

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
        //has data here
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Current Response :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <S:Envelope
     xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <S:Body>
      //has data here
     </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Expected Response:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <S:Envelope
      xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <S:Body>
      // has data here
    </S:Body>
   </S:Envelope>
```

handler-chain.xml :

```
   <handler-chains xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee">
    <handler-chain>
    <handler>
     <handler-class>com.xyz.SoapMsgHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
    </handler-chain>
   </handler-chains>
```

Comment: Your "expected response" is invalid XML: the `xmlns:SOAP-ENV` attribute is there to tell the parser what namespace `SOAP-ENV:Header` refers to. If you remove that attribute, the XML will no longer be parseable. What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: I'm going to guess that your actual problem is that you've written code that relies on the _local prefix_ assigned to a namespace, rather than its _full identifier_. In this case, you should be expecting "element `Header` in namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`", which could be written as `<Header xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`, or `<S:Header xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`, or `<i-am-soap-woohoo:Header xmlns:i-am-soap-woohoo="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`, etc

Comment: In existing java-8 response, we neither had 'xmlns:SOAP-ENV' nor 'SOAP-ENV:Header'. So I am trying to have exact same response.                                        So added these lines  SOAPMessageContext.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:SOAP-ENV");                      SOAPMessageContext.getSOAPHeader().detachNode(); SOAPMessageContext.saveChanges();

Comment: If your previous response was valid SOAP, I assure you it would have had some attribute setting `Header` to be in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`. The fact that you're able to write `getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()` suggests it is being recognised just fine. So, what is the actual error you're trying to deal with by messing around with the XML like this?

Comment: I was not seeing any error. I just wants to match my current response , with existing (java8) response. By doing above lines of code (as I mentioned in my previous comments), my response matches . So issue resolved !!. Thank you

Comment: You haven't actually shown the previous response you're trying to match, but I'm pretty sure *it already matched in all the ways that matter*. Any SOAP parser that is confused by an extra or different xmlns attribute is very broken. Nor should a completely empty Header element matter in the slightest. However, if you think your solution might be useful to others in future, please [write an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so it shows up as answered.